# setup max characters on paragraph

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid, getelementsbyclassname, maxlength

HI guys I tried to setup maxLength to my p using GetElementbyClassName and It doesn't work ? Do you have an idea ? please

```
<td class="tabQuot-col-06">
    <p class="MaxDescription" style="display: inline-block;">PACKING PREFORMED</p>
    <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="PACKING PREFORMED" class="tooltip-custom icon-fi-info" data-original-title="PACKING PREFORMED"></a>
    </td>  

    <script>
    function truncateText(selector, maxLength) {
            var element = document.getElementsByClassName(selector),
                truncated = element.innerText;

            if (truncated.length > maxLength) {
                truncated = truncated.substr(0, maxLength) + '...';
            }
            return truncated;
         }
        document.getElementsByClassName('MaxDescription').innerText = 
        truncateText('MaxDescription', 3);
</script>
```

Comment: maxLength is a property for input/textarea fields, not <p>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is my first answer attempt.

You are getting "undefined" for element.innerText. This is because using document.getElementsByClassName(selector) returns an array of elements. If you want to continue using getElementsByClassName, change your code to "element[0].innerText", or to iterate through the elements if you want to call the function on each element of that class.

Otherwise, you can change "MaxDescription" from class to id, and use document.getElementByID.

Change this:

```
            var element = document.getElementsByClassName(selector),
            truncated = element.innerText;
```

To This:

```
            var element = document.getElementsByClassName(selector),
            truncated = element[0].innerText;
```

For iterating through all elements of that class:

```
            // for iterating through each:
            for(int i = 0; i < element.length < i++){
              var truncated = element[i].innerText;
              if (truncated.length > maxLength) {
                  element[i].innerText = truncated.substr(0, maxLength) + '...';
              }
            }
```

This sets all elements' innerText inside the loop itself, so there is no need to return anything from the function.

Here is a plunker showing the different implementation options you could consider.

https://plnkr.co/edit/o7ELqTQQukSmpcjbO210?p=preview

Hope this helps at least a little.

Comment: Thanks for answering But I have problem if I have another p with the same class still doesn't work for me

Comment: No worries - I believe the loop is what you were looking for! Thanks for accepting my first ever answer.

Comment: Cheers mate !! :)

Answer (score 0):

[**getElementsByClassName**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns a collection of elements, not a single element.

You need to target your first element using `[0]` as JavaScript array are 0-based.
In case you want to apply this script to all your `MaxDescription` elements, you'll need to use a Loop instead.

```js
function truncateText(selector, maxLength) {
  var element = document.getElementsByClassName(selector)[0],
      truncated = element.innerText;

  if (truncated.length > maxLength) {
    truncated = truncated.substr(0, maxLength) + '...';
  }
  return truncated;
}
document.getElementsByClassName('MaxDescription')[0].innerText = truncateText('MaxDescription', 3);
```

```html
<td class="tabQuot-col-06">
    <p class="MaxDescription" style="display: inline-block;">PACKING PREFORMED</p>
    <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="PACKING PREFORMED" class="tooltip-custom icon-fi-info" data-original-title="PACKING PREFORMED"></a>
  </td>
```

Comment: You can also loop on the list returned by document.getElementByClassName.

Answer (score 0):

After the anwsers which help me a lot : 
This is my final code :

```
function truncateText(selector, maxLength) {
    var element = document.getElementsByClassName(selector),
        truncated = element[0].innerText;
    for (var i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {
         var truncated = element[i].innerText;
         if (truncated.length > maxLength) {
              element[i].innerText = truncated.substr(0, maxLength) + '...';
            }
         }
      }
truncateText('MaxDescription', 3);
```